# Añadir un string de otra clase a una que ya tengo

Tags: c#

Os comento, quiero reflejar la versión de ensamblamiento, título y demás y he encontrado un proyecto que trae todo definido en [esta liga](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/353819/Get-all-Assembly-Information).

Bien, al implementarlo en mi otro proyecto he creado una clase que se llama `AssemblyInfo`.

Al intentar llamar a los métodos con un `label` no me funciona, es decir, estoy en `Form1` y quiero llamar a la clase `AssemblyInfo` y al método de versión de ensamblamiento.

**¿Cómo podría hacerlo?**

Estoy intentando añadirlo así:

```
label9.Text = AssemblyInfo.Version();
```

Pero me salen errores ya que así no es el método, si alguien me puede echar una mano y enseñarme el código con el `label` perfecto, para ver la clase en ensamblamiento mirar el enlace.

Comment: Hola Ohh, puedes añadir esos errores que mencionas?  La clase `AssemblyInfo` es estatica? `Version()` devuelve un `String`?

Comment: @lois6b http://image.prntscr.com/image/9d35601e300f4fa4a6faafc1f3be5b3b.png

Comment: @lois6b La línea `string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();` simplemente es de prueba no tiene nada que ver aquí

Comment: no utilices los comentarios para algo relevante de tu pregunta. te sugiero que la [edites](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/50525/edit) para añadir ese codigo de la imagen (pero en formato de texto) y ese comentario de `Version()` tambien. Piensa que un comentario puede ser borrado y no deberia afectar a la resolucion de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Según el error, `Version` no es un método, por lo que lo tendrías que llamar sin el `()`. Pon tu clase `AssemblyInfo` para ver qué es `Version`

Comment: @cnbandicoot esto compi http://image.prntscr.com/image/4dc4071e232543509abf2b0c64529dc4.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu solución parece sencilla. `Version` no es un método, sino una propiedad:

```
label9.Text = AssemblyInfo.Version;
```

Además tendrás que poner tu clase `AssemblyInfo` como `static`:

```
public static class AssemblyInfo
```

Y lo mismo con tu propiedad:

```
public static string Version
```

---

O por el contrario, si no quieres hacer tu clase estática, llámalo de la siguiente manera:

```
AssemblyInfo entryAssemblyInfo = new AssemblyInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
label9.Text = entryAssemblyInfo.Version;
```

Comment: Parece que el OP baso su clase en el enlace de codeproject por lo que la llamada correcta seria la de la forma instanciada. Saludos

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Sí compi, si me pudieses pasar la forma correcta en la que añadir el código me haríais un gran favor. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Prueba de la manera que expongo más abajo @OhhLiberr

Comment: @OhhLiberr La forma correcta esta en la respuesta de cnbandicoot despues del divisor donde te responde: "O por el contrario..."

Comment: @cnbandicootSi compi, lo he probado y no me funciona me sale que Assembly no existe en este contexto

Comment: @OhhLiberr asegurate de tener  using System.Reflection; definido en tu clase donde accedes a la propiedad de entryAssemblyInfo.Version;

Comment: Gracias @JesusRodríguez . Lo acabo de añadir directamente, para que no tenga que importarlo. De todas maneras, muy rápido ;)

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Vale compañeros, muchas gracias por la solución, que error de novato he cometido, jajajaja, de todos modos un placer y muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la version del ensamblado con los siguientes metodos:

```
// Opcion 1

var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version; 
this.Text = String.Format("Version: {0}", version);

// Opcion 2

string version = Application.ProductVersion; 
this.Text = String.Format("Version: {0}", version);

// Opcion 3

this.Text = Application.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: Sí, lo sé, pero quiero usar el proyecto que he mencionado y me gustaría añadir sus códigos en un label.

Comment: Podrias publicar los errores que estas recibiendo.

Comment: AssemblyInfo en el codigo que mencionas no es una clase estatica, necesitas instanciarla antes de poder utilizarala.